# Database-first EF dnx ef dbcontext scaffold command fails

Tags: c#, entity-framework

After using the dnx ef dbcontext scaffold command, I receive the following error:

```
Unable to identify the primary key for table 'dbo.Report'.
Unable to generate entity type for table 'dbo.Report'.
```

Current SQL Schema.

```
 CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Report](
        [ReportID] [int] IDENTITY(1000,1) NOT NULL,
        [ReportName] [varchar](50) NOT NULL,
        [StoredProcedureID] [int] NOT NULL,
        [FileRepositoryID] [int] NULL
    ) ON [PRIMARY]
```

May anyone advise what I may be doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your ReportID column is not set as the primary key. Just simply add the PRIMARY KEY constraint and it should work.

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Report](
    [ReportID] [int] PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY(1000,1) NOT NULL,
    [ReportName] [varchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [StoredProcedureID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [FileRepositoryID] [int] NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

Comment: That worked! Thank you so much! I should read things more carefully.. -_-

Comment: @FBaez51 happens to the best of us! Always something simple haha. Glad I could help